# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

This will be displayed in a mono-spaced font. The first four spaces
    will be stripped off, but all other white space will be preserved.

```
String letterStr = null;
letterStr = (String)((TextView)view).getText();
```

Comment: `getText()` of a `TextView` or `EditText` will return some implementation of a `CharSequence`, which will not necessarily be a `String`.

Comment: this error is not always recurrent ,sometimes happend, why ？hesitation！

Answer (score 7):

the `String` contains html markups, and android treats it as a `Spannable`.

You can either assign the return value of `getText()` to a CharSequence object, which super class for both `String` and `Spannable`, or replace the cast with `toString()`

```
letterStr = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

the former will preserve the html markups, the latter will not

Comment: I getting the same problem "Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
android.text.SpannedString cannot be cast to android.text.Spannable".I used textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(mergedHTML)); 
I'm  facing the problem in  
 GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
@Override
                            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                                super.onLongPress(e);
                                textview.setTextIsSelectable(true);}}});