# Why Im getting this error? java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

When exporting my array list item, Im getting this error. In the first place it works but when updating my code adding data on my array it crashed my app and this error appear, do you have any idea why this happening?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
> cannot be cast to java.lang.String

[image: Logcat_error]

I'm getting error in this line 312 after if statement -

```
mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i,list_items.get(i));
```

I've already tried put empty string on my list like this

```
""+list_items.get(i));
```

but it's not working :(

```
 ArrayList<String> list_items = new ArrayList<String>(); //declared global
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter; //declared global

 public boolean export_data()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();
    mEdit1.putString("Status_","");
    mEdit1.apply();
    mEdit1.putInt("Status_size", list_items.size());

    for(int i=0;i<list_items.size();i++)
    {
        mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);
        if (list_items.get(i) !=null){
            mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i,list_items.get(i));
            String[] separated =  list_items.get(i).split(":");
            mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i, separated[0]);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return mEdit1.commit();
}
```

Adding item on `ArrayAdapter`

```
 public void refreshInbox(){
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);
    ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,"date desc");
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    do{
        String strbody = smsInboxCursor.getString( smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body") );
        if(strbody.contains("Notifier,") && strbody.contains(":")){
            System.out.println ( strbody );
            String str = strbody;
            String[] separated = str.split(",");
            String separate = separated[1];

            String[] sep = separate.split(" : ");
            String sep1 = sep[1];
            String finals = separate.replace(sep1, "<u>"+"<b>" + sep1 +"<b>"+ "</u>");
            arrayAdapter.add(Html.fromHtml(finals));
        }
        else if(strbody.contains("Notifier,") && !strbody.contains(":")){
            System.out.println ( strbody );
            String str = strbody;
            String[] separated = str.split(",");
            String separate = separated[1];
            arrayAdapter.add(separate);
        }
    }while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 312?

Comment: @Michiel Thanks for your response can you help me?  this line after if statement mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i,list_items.get(i));

Comment: I guess the error is not with this line `mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i,list_items.get(i));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you want to keep displaying HTML** in your list view, the problem is that the objects that `ArrayAdapter` is adding `list_items` are not Strings. That means, you have to change how you define the `list_items` variable from String to a more generic character sequence type:

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> list_items = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `CharSequence` interface does not have a "split" method though. To be able to use "split", you'll need to call `toString` to get a regular string:

```
String[] separated =  list_items.get(i).toString().split(":");
```

It would also help if you used the type parameter with your ArrayAdapter. Using the type parameter would have made it harder (if not impossible) to make this mistake.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter;
... inside the method ...
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);
```

Comment: This is what looks like now thank you https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiCrn.png ,  but I wondering, I observed that those bold and underline string has not been properly align same with the other list when retrieving the list in listview do you have any idea? @Joni

Comment: Some of your list items are rendered with Html (the ones with `:` characters), the others are just plain strings - why not make everything use Html? Do the strings maybe start with blank space characters? You get rid of those with a  call to `.trim()`

Comment: Thank you!, I make everything Html to align list it works!, but one more last question if you mind, I'm just curious but not related to this topic ,regarding to the compatibility of the android version. I have already run my entire application in my android version 5.1 but the thing is when I run it to the version 9 in terms of reading SMS inbox the app did not allow the permission same with this topic below, could I change the permission code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621862/read-sms-failed-to-read-in-android  @Joni

Answer (score 0):

```java
list_items.get(i));
```

Looks like you might be attempting to put an unusual type of string into the list...

see: [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393478/java-lang-classcastexception-android-text-spannablestring-cannot-be-cast-to-jav?rq=1)

I'm not an android dev but I suspect there are some "useful" shortcuts it provides in an attempt to make your life easier, that would probably trip you up.

Groovy's default string was a GString rather than a String. That tripped me up a number of times before I got used to it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is with this line in `refreshInbox()`

```
 arrayAdapter.add(Html.fromHtml(finals));
```

**Html.fromHtml** does't return String but instead it retuns **Spanned**

But you need to pass String to **add()** on **adapter**

To fix this convert it to String

```
adapter.add(Html.fromHtml(finals).toString()); // this will return plain text without html tags
```

or

```
adapter.add(finals); // this will be having HTML tags from this you can set text on views later
```